# In xcode 6.1 and os x yosemite is not supporting ios 7.1 and below version?

Tags: ios

i recently updated xcode 6.1 and os x yosemite but xcode is not supporting the ios 7.1 and below version, so please help me.
if i select the ipad 7.1 or iphone 5s below version it appears the image below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In OS X 10.10 (Yosemite Beta), How do I Test Using iOS 6.1 Simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901287/in-os-x-10-10-yosemite-beta-how-do-i-test-using-ios-6-1-simulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, iOS 7.1 simulator is not get downloaded,

```
 Go to preferences --> Downloads --> click for download
```

[image]

[And the below versions is no more available via the Xcode 6.1 version.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631551/run-app-in-ios-6-simulator-in-xcode-6)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i downloaded the ios 7.1 simulator and its working fine.