# iOS Simulator - Test on iOS 8.0 instead of iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

Is there a way to force the iPhone Simulator to run iOS 8.0 instead of iOS 8.1?

We have an issue here that affects 8.0 builds, but not 8.1, and would like to replicate the issue on the simulator.

Comment: Check my answer **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607814/in-xcode-6-1-and-os-x-yosemite-is-not-supporting-ios-7-1-and-below-version/26607877#26607877**

Answer (score 3):

if you enrolled at apple developer program, you can download previous versions of Xcode. 
If you download Xcode 6.0.1 then you'll get ios 8.0.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the only way so far. Hopefully there will be an 8.0 simulator made available in the future.

Answer (score -2):

Open Xcode->Preferences->Downloads

Lower version simulators will be shown in the 'components' section. You can download and install them manually.

Comment: I see some older versions there, but not 7 or 8.0. It may be because they're already on my machine. In that case do you know where I an enable them?

Comment: In that case, goto [link](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and install xcode 6.0 (if you are enrolled for apple developer program). It comes with iOS Simulator 8.0 bundled.