# iOS application name not show in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6.1, xcode6.1.1

I have created a iPhone application using Xcode 6.1. And works perfectely.

If i run Application in iOS 6.1 os version's devices it show only app icon alone and not show app name.

But it show normally in iOS 8 os version's devices.

Below 1st mage is iOS8 and second one is iOS 6.1

How can i solve this issue?

Hope some one help....

[image]

[image]

Comment: Support of iOS 6 development is ended, it seems that you somehow have hacked the Xcode and now facing that issue

Comment: If i do some thing with xcode mean , how my other application run with out this issue?

Comment: Check for example that [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24631738/1565335)

Answer (score 1):

I have check my Bundle setting in my application **Target's Bundle settings** and **Project's Bundle settings** with Product name , I have set as a new name.

But it also wont resolve this issue.

So i have test with **info.plist** file,

Finally i have found a **"Bundle display name"** and i have set as **"$(PRODUCT_NAME)"** (Like a below image ) and it resolve my issue .

Now iOS 6.1 also show application name.   :)

[image]